# Character is not moving foward when setting body type to Dynamic

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

Currently I have 1 problem when moving character toward x position using this code

```
     Vector3 temp = transform.position;
     temp.x += forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
     transform.position = temp;
```

Below is the settings of inspector

[image]

If I set body type to `Dynamic` character can move up and down but if I set body type to `Kinematic` character can move foward but when I click to the screen character will jump out of the screen.

Below is my source code and I hope everyone can point me out what I have done wrong

My source [code](https://github.com/ngohungphuc/unity/tree/master/src/GameLearning/Flappy%20Bird)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You should be using [Rigidbody2D.MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) to move rigidbodies.

```
Vector3 temp = transform.position;
temp.x += forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

var rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
rb.MovePosition(temp);
```

You can also use `rb.position = temp` but `MovePosition()` provides the best collision detection.

---

If this doesn't work either, you have colliders blocking your rigidbody in the forward direction, preventing it from moving that way. In that case, check the object's hierarchy, including its children.

Comment: But how can move toward if I I has box collider ?

Comment: You need to enable layer-based collision. Have your bird's colliders be on a specific layer, which doesn't collide with itself, and your environment on its own layer, which collides with your player layer. You can find more info about it in the docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html --- Make sure you use the Physics2D panel, as it has a different Layer-Based-Collision Table than the Physics one (which is for 3D)

Comment: Turn out I need to enable layer based collision for physic 2d not physic. Thank you for pointing out